# My copy constructor is messing up the first element in my list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

Below is the code for my copy constructor or rather my overload function but my instructor calls it a copy constructor:

```
void operator=(const Stack& s)
    {
        if (s.top == NULL)
            top == NULL;
        else
        {
            top = new Node;
            top->link = s.top->link;
            Node* newP = top;

                for(Node* curr = s.top->link; curr != NULL; curr = curr->link)
                {
                    newP->link = new Node;
                    newP = newP->link;
                    newP->data = curr->data;
                }
        }
    }
```

The input i expect to receive i will show in an image below along with the input i get.
[image]

It is my understanding that NULL is equal to 0 so i'm wondering if my s.top being set equal to NULL is stopping a successful copy.

Comment: A copy-constructor is completely different and that doesn't free the previously used memory.

Comment: is that why the copy is coming up wrong?

Comment: the function you show is not a copy-constructor, it's a copy-*assignment* operator.

Comment: Oh, and I hope your `Node` constructor properly sets `link` to zero (i.e. `NULL`).

Comment: Thirdly, the line `top->link = s.top->link;` can be removed.

Comment: And lastly, use a debugger to step though the code line by line, and you will most likely find the fault pretty quickly.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg when you mention my node constructor do you mean `top = new Node` should be `top->link = new Node`? Well now that i think of it that seems very wrong.

Comment: No, I mean that you have a `Node::Node` function, that does e.g. `this->link = 0;`

Comment: oh yes, there's a main class implementing this class, i just figured it wasn't necessary to post it since the main class was coded by my instructor and the error is within my functions

Answer (score 1):

I've annotated the code below with what I think fixes your issue.

```
void operator=(const Stack& s)
{
    if (s.top == NULL)
        top == NULL; // make sure you delete the existing nodes if there are any - this looks like a leak
    else
    {
        top = new Node; 
        top->link = s.top->link; // you need to remove this line you will allocate a new link later
        top->data = s.top->data; // this is the missing line messing with your first node
        Node* newP = top;

        for (Node* curr = s.top->link; curr != NULL; curr = curr->link)
        {
            newP->link = new Node; 
            newP = newP->link; // here's your issue - on the first iteration you're stepping over the first node but you never set the data for it
            newP->data = curr->data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So would `top->data = newP` suffice above the line marked as the issue?

Comment: Also after your edits it copies right, but the size of the list still isn't printing out right